# How to set a download path to a local drive in client using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, download, hard-drive

I'm trying to set a link in my asp.net website such that the file downloads directly to a specific local disk on the client.

For Eg: `E:\output\report.pdf`

Can anyone help me with the coding ?

Comment: How do you know that the client is a Windows OS, and that this specific path exists ?

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a flaw in your concept - a website should never have knowledge of the contents of your hard drive.

Therefore, setting a specific download path is not only impossible (that I know of, at least), it is conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are deliberately isolated from the local filesystem in order to prevent scripting attacks. You cannot get this information.

You can explore **Request.Browser in asp.net** then you know what information you have about client. some exmaples are here

```
    Request.Browser.BackgroundSounds
    Request.Browser.Browser
    Request.Browser.Version
    Request.Browser.Platform
```